# Updating the value in column in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to pass a column2 to a function and update column3 with output of function. I have made func function to calculae the output. When i run the program
it only takes last value as input and outputs all columns with same value.What am i doing wrong?

```
sqlite1 = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource = D:/datab.db;version=3");
sqlite1.Open();
string query1 = "select * from ramrotable";
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query1, sqlite1);
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age::" + reader["age"]);
    //int data = Convert.ToInt16(reader["age"]);
    string tempquery = string.Format("UPDATE ramrotable SET num = 
                       func({0})",reader["age"]);
    cmd = new SQLiteCommand(tempquery, sqlite1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

string query4 = "select * from ramrotable";
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query4, sqlite1);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + reader["name"] + " Age: " +  
                       reader["age"] + " Num: " + reader["num"]);          
}
```

Comment: Your update statement is updating all rows in the table with the current value on each iteration of the loop since you don't specify what rows to update using a restricting `where` clause.

Comment: I want to update each column from value of another column from same row . How to do it? what to add in where clause

Comment: Also the operation needs to be done on all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `WHERE` clause to tell SQLite which record to update exactly. Otherwise all records will be affected. Please make sure that in the `WHERE` clause you use a column (or a combination of columns) the identify the record uniquely!

Ideally, every record will have an `ID` column that contains a unique value and is the Primary Key.

---

I understand from the comments to the question that you actually want to update the value of the `num` column depending on a value from the `age` column *of the same record*, for all the records in the table.

To do this, you neither need to fetch all the records nor do you need to loop. All you need to do is invoke the following statement:

```
UPDATE ramrotable SET num = func(age)
```

This takes the value of the `age` column, passes it to `func` and sets the result as the new value for the `num` column *for each record in the table*.

So all of what you've written above can be shortened to

```
sqlite1 = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource = D:/datab.db;version=3");
sqlite1.Open();

cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE ramrotable SET num =  func(age)", sqlite1);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
string tempquery = string.Format("UPDATE ramrotable SET num = 
                   func({0})",reader["age"]);
```

you are updating each row with current func(age) value.

For updating each row with exact value you should use single command outside of the while loop:

```
string updatequery = "UPDATE ramrotable SET num = func(age)";
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(updatequery, sqlite1);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```